# Python + Kivy Interface with custom functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to build an interface for an script that I wrote which handles automatic replies to users based on a ticket they submit.

I'm encountering errors when I try to convert my functions for use in the app.

The code that isn't working properly is as follows,

```
class MyApp(App):

    o = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    ol = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')

    def sf(self):

        folders = self.o.Folders
        tardir = self.root.ids.label.main_inbox

        for folder in folders:
            if folder.Name == tardir:
                return folder
            folderMatch = self.sf()
            if folderMatch:
                return folderMatch
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "_ctypes/callbacks.c", line 234, in 'calling callback function'
   File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\input\providers\wm_touch.py", line 127, in _touch_wndProc
     lParam)
 ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'RecursionError'>: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

The function from my original code, pre-interface is as follows

```
def sf(folders, tardir):    
    for folder in folders:  # if `folder` follows python convention, it should be iterable.
        if folder.Name == tardir: # is it the correct folder?
            return folder 
        folderMatch = sf(folder.Folders, tardir)  # recurse into child folders
        if folderMatch: 
            # return result from recursive call of sf() if successful
            return folderMatch
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated... I'm rather lost.

****EDIT AFTER SUGGESTED ANSWER****

I implemented this change, and when trying to use the function I get the error stating that

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python\Python36\emailBotInterface.py", line 175, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 802, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "C:\Python\Python36\emailBotInterface.py", line 108, in build
     label.unhandled_requests = self.config.get(get_folderMatch())
 NameError: name 'get_folderMatch' is not defined
```

I tried using the function in this manner:

```
def build(self):
        """
        Build and return the root widget.
        """

        # The line below is optional. You could leave it out or use one of the
        # standard options, such as SettingsWithSidebar, SettingsWithSpinner
        # etc.
        self.settings_cls = MySettingsWithTabbedPanel

        # We apply the saved configuration settings or the defaults
        root = Builder.load_string(kv)
        label = root.ids.label
        label.main_inbox = self.config.get('Mail Config', 'main_inbox')
        label.comments_folder = self.config.get('Mail Config', 'comments_folder')
        label.excess_folder = self.config.get('Mail Config', 'excess_folder')
        label.search_string = self.config.get('Mail Config', 'search_string')
        label.unhandled_requests = self.config.get(MyApp.get_folderMatch())

        return root
```

Comment: Apologies, it wasn't clear. I just changed the name of the function to match what I had. My naming schemes can be abysmal, but typically it's only ever code that I look at. One moment, I'll edit the post.

Comment: I corrected it to match your suggestion. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: What should be the argument passed through the function?

Comment: I am executing it in the build() method. The idea behind using it is to get configurations that won't ever manually be changed, however the will change depending on the other variables that are able to be modified.

Comment: NoneType Error using that approach `root = self.build()
   File "C:\Python\Python36\emailBotInterface.py", line 108, in build
     label.unhandled_requests = self.config.get(self.get_folderMatch())
   File "C:\Python\Python36\emailBotInterface.py", line 89, in get_folderMatch
     folderMatch = MyApp.sf(MyApp.o.Folders, self.root.ids.label.main_inbox)
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ids'`

Comment: ' File "C:\Python\Python36\emailBotInterface.py", line 103, in build
     label = root.ids.label
 NameError: name 'root' is not defined' occurs after that change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code was provided by eyllanesc which helped in finding the issue. Instead of trying to use `self.config.get(get_folderMatch())` I realized that I don't need to display this configuration. So, I just created the attribute for label and assigned like so, `label.unhandled_requests = self.get_folderMatch(label.main_inbox)` and everything works great.

```
@staticmethod
def sf(folders, tardir):    
    for folder in folders:  # if `folder` follows python convention, it should be iterable.
        if folder.Name == tardir: # is it the correct folder?
            return folder 
        folderMatch = MyApp.sf(folder.Folders, tardir)  # recurse into child folders
        if folderMatch: 
            # return result from recursive call of sf() if successful
            return folderMatch

def get_folderMatch(self, tardir):
    folderMatch = MyApp.sf(MyApp.o.Folders, self.root.ids.label.main_inbox)
    return folderMatch
```